# What is VideoCore MMU used for?

Tags: memory

In RaspberryPI architecture (Broadcom BM2328 SoC), we can see that ARM core physical memory is mapped to VideoCore memory through a second MMU (the first maps ARM virtual to physical memory). What is the use of this configuration? Doesn't the use of 2 MMU's increase the latency?

Answer (score 1):

One MMU maps ARM virtual addresses (used by Linux userland and the kernel) into ARM physical addresses.

The other MMU maps ARM physical addresses into bus addresses (to access the peripherals such as the gpio, DMA, SPI, UARTs etc. etc.).

I doubt that either MMU adds any latency.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but does it mean that VideoCore GPU is what really manages every memory accesses?

Comment: @Pierre I do not know.  I don't think so.  I believe it's only the peripheral address space which needs to be accessed via the VC GPU MMU.  You'd need to find someone familiar with ARM architecture - and that is not me.

Comment: Eight years late: but yes! The VC MMU manages _all_ memory. DRAM is actually not necessarily contiguous on the bus and so the VC MMU helps hide this from the ARM. The VC MMU only manages a few mappings and so is significantly faster than the ARM MMU. Also, note, that this is after the ARM L2 and so an additional 5-10 cycles would be negligible on a full miss out to DRAM anyways.